# how to unit-test setInterval in karma angularjs

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive, setinterval, karma-runner

```
app.directive('shuffleBlocks', function($timeout){
    return {
        link: function(sco,ele,att){
            if (itemCnt <= 1) return;

            /*Trigger function*/
            function triggerEvent(){
                ...
            }
            ele.bind('click', triggerEvent);

            setInterval(triggerEvent, 5000);
        }
    }
})
```

here I wrote the test

```
        var elem = '<div shuffle-blocks><div>';
        elem = mockCompile(elem)(rootScope.$new());
        setInterval(function(){
            expect(......).toBe(....)
        });
```

Obviously this is not the right method,
does anyone know how to test $timeout and setInterval in karma?

Comment: The latest version of angular (1.2.0-rc3) has an $interval service that makes testing this kind of functionality much easier. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interval

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The proper method of mocking setInterval in an angular 1.2+ application is to use angular's `$interval` service. Using the `$interval` service provides a number of benefits, but the one of most use in this situation is the `$interval.flush()` method. When writing tests, `$interval` exposes a `.flush()` method which allows you to mock the JS clock.

```
app.directive('shuffleBlocks', function($timeout, $interval){
    return {
        link: function(sco,ele,att){
            if (itemCnt <= 1) return;

            /*Trigger function*/
            function triggerEvent(){ ... }
            ele.bind('click', triggerEvent);

            $interval(triggerEvent, 5000);
        }
    }
});
```

and then in your unit test:

```
var elem = '<div shuffle-blocks><div>';
elem = mockCompile(elem)(rootScope.$new());
$interval.flush(5000); // flush accepts the # of ms to be flushed
expect(......).toBe(....);
```

Hope that's helpful to anyone who looks up this answer in the future. I'll leave my previous answer for those still using 1.1X.

---

**Previous Answer:** According the [jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Jasmine_Clock), you should be able to just use the `jasmine.Clock.useMock()` function to mock the typical javascript clock and manually work your way through the interval.  Since angular is just wrapping the native `setTimeout` function, I'm quite positive it should allow this to work, though I haven't tested it to be sure.

The jasmine docs for version 1.3 are [here](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Clock).  Here's the code example that demonstrates how it works.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    timerCallback = jasmine.createSpy('timerCallback');
    jasmine.Clock.useMock();
});

it("causes a timeout to be called synchronously", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        timerCallback();
    }, 100);

    expect(timerCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    jasmine.Clock.tick(101);

    expect(timerCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The only issue I see is that your `triggerEvent()` function is local to your link function, so I don't know how you'll be able to get to it to mock it.  But hopefully that points you in the right direction.  If not, sorry, I tried.

**UPDATE:** The syntax for mocking the clock has changed in `Jasmine 2.0`. If you are using 2.0, please see the updated docs [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Timeout_Functions).

Comment: Most certainly. Always a bit of a shame to have to break encapsulation just for testing, but in many cases making something testable automatically makes it flexible/configurable/extensible.

Comment: Syntax changed in Jasmine 2.0: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Timeout_Functions

Comment: Good idea. I updated my response to include the docs for 2.0.