# Angular unit testing $interval for a "clock" directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have an Angular directive "clock" and **I'm trying to write a unit test to see if the clock actually $interval advances to a future time** (ie: 2 minutes by looking at `element.text()`).   I have a passing test of the current time, now I want to test if it will show a future time via `$interval.flush`.   It appears to me `$interval.flush` isn't really advancing the clock.

Can I ask for two answers:

- How do I unit test if `$interval` fires?
- Why `$interval.flush` doesn't seem to advance the `Date()`?

I'm following guidelines from these posts:

- [how to unit-test setInterval in karma angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505494/how-to-unit-test-setinterval-in-karma-angularjs)
- http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/15/unit-testing-interval-angularls/

A related post suggested using Jasmine mocks, which I don't think is necessary anymore.

- [Testing a $interval with Jasmine in PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994013/testing-a-interval-with-jasmine-in-phantomjs)

A similar problem:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/5TFvCa5m8n0

## HTML

```
  <mydatething format="EEEE, MMMM d" interval="1000" timezone="notused"></mydatething>
```

## DIRECTIVE

```
myApp.directive('mydatething', ['$interval', 'dateFilter', function ($interval, dateFilter) {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: {
      format: '@',
      interval: '@'
    },
    template: '', // the template is the Date() output
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      // scope expects format, interval and timezone
      var clockid;
      var clockinterval = scope.interval;
      var dateformat = scope.format;
      var clocktimezone = scope.timezone;

      // DOM update function
      function updateClock() {
        element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), dateformat));
      }

      // Instantiate clock
      updateClock();
      clockid = $interval(updateClock, clockinterval); // fixed

      // For cancelling 
      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $interval.cancel(clockid);
      });

      // Separate listener for locale change, manually refresh clock format
      scope.$on('$localeChangeSuccess', function () {
        updateClock();
      })
    }
  };
}]);
```

## UNIT TEST

```
describe("tsdate directive", function(){
  var elem, scope, $interval, dateFilter;
    beforeEach(module('tsApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$interval_, _$compile_, _dateFilter_){
    $compile = _$compile_;
    dateFilter = _dateFilter_;
    $interval = _$interval_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    elem = angular.element('<mydatething format="h:mm a" interval="15000"></mydatething>');
    elem = $compile(elem)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    }));
    describe('on clock start', function() {
    it('to show the current date', function() {
      var currentdate = dateFilter(new Date(), elem.isolateScope().format);
      expect(elem.text()).toBe(currentdate);
      // this passes
    });
    it('that it updates the clock', function() {
      var futurems = 120000; // 2 minutes
      var futuredate = dateFilter(new Date().getTime() + futurems, elem.isolateScope().format)
      $interval.flush(futurems);
      expect(elem.text()).toBe(futuredate);
     // this fails
    });
    });

});
```

## TERMINAL

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) mydatething directive on clock start that it updates the clock FAILED
    Expected '3:55' to be '3:57'.
```

`Console.log` reveals, the `futuredate` var is 2 minutes incremented, but that the `elem.text()` remains the current time.

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: Yes and no, I can test the function updateClock() to see if it performs as expected but it wasn't worth delving into actually having a test run X minutes just to see if the clock reflects X min in the future.  I refactored so that updateClock receives a new Date instead of generating one.  Therefore, I can spyOn updateClock to see if it fires in the interval specified, and to see if updateClock's text updates if I pass it a future date variable.  In a way js "Date" is out of scope, it's the computer's own software, we presume they've done their own due diligence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE BEFORE I START:

You have an error in your directive code. When calling $interval, you pass the function object as the first parameter. No parenthesis.

```
// Do this
clockid = $interval(updateClock, clockinterval);

// Not this
clockid = $interval(updateClock(), clockinterval);
```

See the difference on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yEcoExCfdx6NSZRNDlX1?p=preview)

Secondly, calling $interval.flush causes interval to move forward by the number of milliseconds, but it has not effect on the internal Javascript clock. Since you are using Date to update the time on the clock, you are always getting the current time. Calling $interval.flush may cause interval to update the clock a bunch of times, but it's always setting it to the current time.

Comment: Thanks. I see now its not like I'm running a virtual clock, Date() exists in real time, so unless `gulp test` is going to wait a whole minute, I can't call forth the future.  Is Jasmine's clock mock meant to do this or should I simply look at making sure $interval is called as a test.

Comment: @liquified You are going to have to wait for the full two minutes. But there are some gotchas. The intervals to update the clock in your angular code to not get called when you run Jasmine. You have do it manually. You also need to set a timeout to run the "expect" function in your test, tell Jasmine not to throw a timeout error. And last of all, you need to make a change to your karma.config to include "browserNoActivityTimeout: 122000". I've included two files in my plunk: test.js and karma.config.js. See the code comments. http://plnkr.co/edit/yEcoExCfdx6NSZRNDlX1

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use `$scope.$apply()` after the $interval to ensure the Angular knows about it.